# If I have T observations from a binomial(n,p), how to consistently estimate n and p?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, binomial-distribution, aic, consistency

Suppose I have a dataset $\{S_t\}_{t=1}^T$, where $S_t\overset{i.i.d.}{\sim}Binomial(n,p)$, how to consistently estimate $n$ and $p$ using this dataset? It would be great if you could provide a method with theoretical guarantee for consistency. I thought about MLE, which does not give me consistency via standard argument, because the loglikelihood is not differentiable in $n$.  Another approach I thought about is to consider the estiamtion of $n$ and $p$ separately: do MLE for each given $n$ and select $n$ using AIC or BIC. Is there any hope for consistency using this approach?

Comment: Can't you use the method of moments? Recover method of moments estimates for the mean and variance (which are functions of both parameters in the population) which then gives you two equations and two unknowns. Method of moments gives you consistent estimates in very general conditions.

Comment: Also the likelihood doesn't need to be differentiable for the consistency results to hold; the place you tend to need differentiability is asymptotic normality (since the proof usually requires a Taylor expansion of the first order condition; I'm not sure this is strictly necessary though)

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty Thank you very much, Yashaswi! This is very helpful!